# Symfony2 PagerFantaBundle

Tags: php, symfony, pagerfanta

I'm try to use the [WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle)

I did follow the install. But the pagination does not work.

Here is my controller:

```
$client = $this->getUser()->getsite()->getClient();
$registersQB = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Activity\Register')->findAllByClient($client);

$pagerfanta = new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($registersQB));
$pagerfanta->setMaxPerPage(4);
$registers = $pagerfanta;

$tpl = 'AppBundle:Activity/Register:index.html.twig';

return $this->render($tpl, [
    'registers' => $registers
]);
```

And here is the twig rendering:

```
{{ pagerfanta(registers, 'twitter_bootstrap3') }}
```

The pagination is here, but when i'm liking in the previous link, it always display the same page (page one).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work like that:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $params['page'] = (int)$request->query->get('page', 1);
    $params['limit'] = (int)$request->query->get('limit', 4);

    $client = $this->getUser()->getsite()->getClient();
    $registersQB = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Activity\Register')->findAllByClient($client);

    $pagerfanta = new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($registersQB));
    $pagerfanta->setMaxPerPage($params['limit'])->setCurrentPage($params['page']);

    $registers = $pagerfanta;

    $tpl = 'AppBundle:Activity/Register:index.html.twig';

    return $this->render($tpl, [
        'registers' => $registers,
        'client' => $client
    ]);
}
```